# Issues with hosting AngularJS and images

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, azure, web-hosting

I'd like to preface this question by stating that I am extremely new to development, so apologies in advance.

Essentially, I have deployed my site to Azure -everything worked great on LocalHost, deployed everything works except for the angular and the images.

For my images:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) windmillcontractors.azurewebsites.net/images/windmillFreshCut64.png

I have the incorrect path, but I'm unsure what I'm missing to correct it. I'd also like to note my favicon is not displaying, which I assume is for the same reason as its within the same folder as windmillFreshCut64.png.

For the Angular:

I get an error that leads me to believe upon instantiating, Angular can't find the dependencies. Here it is:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/$injector/modulerr?p0=registrationModule…angularjs.org%2F1.2.16%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3Dn%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Er......1) angular?v=Yj0JoRijZo-WbXksXxT7R8FZxhv6PQ59Vkm83GDIbm41:1

[Angular Error Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24injector/modulerr?p0=registrationModule&p1=Error%3a%20%5B%24injector%3aunpr%5D%20http%3a%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.16%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3Dn%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Er) and [More Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24injector/unpr?p0=n)

Here's my registration-module:

```
var registrationModule = angular.module('registrationModule', ['ngRoute',       'ngResource'])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/Estimates', { templateUrl: 'Scripts/templates/estimates.html',     controller: 'EstimatesCtrl' })
 .otherwise('/');
//.when('/Portal/Customers', { templateUrl: 'templates/customers.html', controller:    'CustomersCtrl' })
//$locationProvider.html5mode(true);
});

registrationModule.controller('EstimatesCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope) {

    $http.get("Portal/Estimates").success(function(data){ $scope.estimates =     data}).error(function(data){console.log(data)});



 $scope.viewEstimate = function (estimate) {
    $rootScope.estimate = estimate;
};


$scope.currentPage = 0;
$scope.pageSize = 20;

$scope.data = $http.get("Portal/Estimates").success(function (data) { $scope.estimates   = data }).error(function (data) { console.log(data) });

//$scope.estimateArray = jQuery.makeArray($scope.data);

//$scope.dataArray = Array.prototype.slice.call($scope.data);
//$scope.newArray = [];

//for (var key in $scope.data) {
//    $scope.newArray.push(key);
//};

//alert(jQuery.makeArray($scope.data));

//Object.keys($scope.data)
$scope.numberOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.data.length / $scope.pageSize);//not working

$scope.resetFilter = function () {
    $route.reload();
}


});

registrationModule.filter('isoToMS', function () {
return function (input) {
    var dateAsFromServerSide = input;

    var parsedDate = new Date(parseInt(dateAsFromServerSide.substring(6)));

    var jsDate = new Date(parsedDate); //Date object

    return jsDate;
};
});

registrationModule.filter('startFrom', function () {
return function (input, start) {
    start = +start; //parse to int
    return input.slice(start);
}
});
```

**Here's my bundle config:**

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/angular.js",
                 "~/Scripts/angular-resource.js",
                 "~/Scripts/angular-route.js",
                 "~/Scripts/Registration-Module/registration-module.js"
               ));
```

Thanks

Comment: How do you have your route for the static image directory defined in ASP.NET MVC? If you have a catch-all route that may be the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have bundled the javascript and it is minifying your scripts the service names will be mangled and you need to use the following pattern in declaring your controllers

```
    registrationModule.controller('EstimatesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootscope', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
       $http.get("Portal/Estimates")
          .success(function(data){
             $scope.estimates = data
           })
          .error(function(data){console.log(data)});
       $scope.viewEstimate = function (estimate) {
       $rootScope.estimate = estimate;
    };
  }]);
```

This will allow angular to inject the dependencies by the appropriate string names which will be preserved during minimization.

Comment: The square brackets are in the wrong place. The function should be inside the array. Otherwise it looks like it should solve the problem. :)

Comment: thanks guys, I have amended the code as suggested and with Jim Schuberts answer I have a better understanding of what is wrong. I still don't have it working but at least I know what the error is. Here's my update:                      registrationModule.controller('EstimatesCtrl',      ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope)     {

    $http.get("Portal/Estimates").success(function(data){ $scope.estimates = data}).error(function(data){console.log(data)});
    
    $scope.viewEstimate = function (estimate) {
        $rootScope.estimate = estimate;
    };
}]);

Answer (score 1):

Your angular error is because you haven't setup your controller properly for minification.

```
registrationModule.controller('EstimatesCtrl',[ // notice the array brackets
    '$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', // annotated with injected dependencies
    function ($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
    // etc.
    }
  ] // be sure to close the array
);
```

When you minify angular doesn't know what to inject. Here's what your controller is when it's minified:

```
registrationModule.controller("EstimatesCtrl", function(n, t, i) {
    t.get("Portal/Estimates").success(function(t) {
        n.estimates = t
    }).error(function(n) {
        console.log(n)
    });
    n.viewEstimate = function(n) {
        i.estimate = n
    };
    n.currentPage = 0;
    n.pageSize = 20;
    n.data = t.get("Portal/Estimates").success(function(t) {
        n.estimates = t
    }).error(function(n) {
        console.log(n)
    });
    n.numberOfPages = Math.ceil(n.data.length / n.pageSize);
    n.resetFilter = function() {
        $route.reload()
    }
});
```

The way AngularJS determines what to inject into your function is by taking the function and calling `toString()`, then parsing out the names of the parameters. It's failing here because you don't have services called `n`, `t`, or `i`.

by calling it with the array of injector-annotated dependencies, it would become:

```
registrationModule.controller("EstimatesCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', function(n, t, i) {
    // etc
}]);
```

Now, `n == $scope`, `t == $http` and `$rootScope == i`. Since minifying code doesn't mangle strings, AngularJS knows what registered services need to get injected.

edit: I forgot to mention.. this needs to be done anywhere there is dependency injection. Check out the [dependency injection documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) for more info.